# How control javascript error when json is empty

Tags: javascript, json

I am parsing a JSON file in javascript. Every 5 minutes the JSON is autoimatically updated with new data, during the time it is being updated the JSON is blank (for a about 2 seconds).

I get this error

> Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input
>       at fetch.then.res

This is the code in javascript for parsing the JSON:

```
 fetch("http://location/file/data.json")
          .then(res => res.json()) 
          .then(data => {
            //do something
          })
```

How do I control this so that it doesn't flag this error? I still want an a customer error to appear using `console.log(Error())`.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do the trick. `then()` takes a second callback function as argument that receives the error object.

```
fetch("http://location/file/data.json")
          .then(res => res.json(), err => console.log(err)) 
          .then(data => {
            //do something
          }, err => console.log(err))
```

**EDIT:** As per comment, this way is preferred. Can read more about using promises in this [link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Using_promises)

```
fetch("http://location/file/data.json")
          .then(res => res.json()) 
          .then(data => {
            //do something
          })
          .catch(err => console.log(err)
```

Comment: While this works, `.catch` is the canonical and proper way to log the error. In future Node versions (and likely browsers too), not having the `.catch` will halt execution.

Answer (score 2):

You can add `.catch` into your processing:

```
 fetch("http://location/file/data.json")
     .then(res => res.json()) 
     .then(data => {
         // do something
     })
     .catch(err => console.log(err.message))
```

EDIT: `err.message` instead of `JSON.stringify(err)`.

Comment: Note that in a browser, the JSON.stringify isn't necessary.

Comment: @BenCooper: Good point, it's a habit of mine. `err.message` would be maybe the best here.